# Stackuserflow - userscript collection

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, google-chrome

Script series to modify the functionality of the network sites. Before using them you should have:

- In *Google Chrome* install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
- In *Firefox* install [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
- In *Opera* install [Tampermonkey](https://addons.opera.com/pt/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/?display=en)

Repository: https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey

---

### Userscript collection

#### ChatFullName

Show full name in chat [<kbd>Install</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/ChatFullName.user.js)

- Github: [source](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/ChatFullName.user.js)
- Preview:

  > [image: show full name in chat]

---

#### Highlight

Highlight questions with favorite tags (for help people with [color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) problem) [<kbd>Install</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/Highlight.user.js)

In script source change to the desired color:

[`var bgColor = '#FCA';`](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/Highlight.user.js#L29)

- Github: [source](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/Highlight.user.js)
- Preview:

  > [image: chat hightlight color]

---

#### Bye Stars, Bye

Remove fixed (by "star") messages in chat by ower chat room [<kbd>Install</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/ByeStars-Bye.user.js)

- Github: [source](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/ByeStars-Bye.user.js)
- Preview:

  > [image: remove owner stars]

---

#### CleanChat

Theme for chat [<kbd>Install</kbd>](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/raw/master/CleanChat.user.js)

- Github: [source](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey/blob/master/CleanChat.user.js)
- Preview:

  > [image: Clean chat]

Comment: @BrockAdams Yes I was aware of this, is that some people uses the "developer mode", but removed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but even developer mode userscripts are now blocked by Chrome unless they are uploaded and approved to the Chrome store! (Which is a PITA and deal breaker for most userscripts.)